# What is the difference using simple random effects between coxme and coxph?

Tags: r, mixed-model, survival

I cannot find somewhere where it is clearly stated the difference between using `coxme` and `coxph` functions in R. My interest is mostly in the case of simple random effects.

I don't have a real data to work on but let's imagine a vey simple situation: I have a dataset that includes data from a cohort recruited in a specific period in the past. The participants were enrolled in different areas of country, each corresponding to a recruiment centre (`centre`). I am interested in the association between a treatment (`treatment`) and a time-to-event outcome (`time` as time to the event and `status` as indicator for event occurrence). There are also other variables involved which might act as confounders (`covariates`), so I decide to include them in the model as well.

If I had to run a Cox Proportional Hazards model, the syntax would be this:

- `coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ treatment + covariates + (1|centre))`
- `coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ treatment + covariates + frailty(centre))`

From what I was able to understand reading on the web, the main difference everything is left as default, is that in coxme the random effect has distribution $N(0,1)$, while in coxph the frailty term is distributed as a $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, but I don't know the value for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Is that the only difference?

I found some info on [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/130315.html) old thread from 2007, but considering that the packages might have been updated, I wonder if someone has clearer and more definitive insights on this.